# Move dialog modal window above strut in gtk+

Tags: c, gtk, x11

I need to have a dialog window placed above another window, the dialog is slightly smaller than the main window.
The main window has strut set on it, and while it is set the dialog will not move above the parent completely, but "maxes out" on it's X being about 50 pixels to the left of the main window, no matter what I set the X to be (using gtk_window_move).
I have worked around it by deleting and recreating the strut, but this causes a significant visible flash.

Is there any way to make this work better?

Comment: What is a "strut"? And are you setting your transient window properly?

Comment: Try calling `gtk_window_set_geometry_hints()` and setting `GDK_HINT_POS` and/or `GDK_HINT_USER_POS`.

Comment: @andlabs [this is a strut](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472580736).